# Google Maps API and XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, google-maps

I've been trying to learn how to put multiple markers on a google map using their online tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3. I am using wamp 2.5 to test it out. I've copied their database and the code and changed the php database connection to the new version but I am still getting the error

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.

The document tree is shown below.

```
<markers/></em>
```

Here is the code I used from the website. Am I missing something, why am I getting this error?

```
    <?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = $db_connection->query($query);

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by encoding the database query into json, passing the json to a javascript function that would create a javascript array and then using the newly created array with the google API. Probably not the right or easiest way to do it but it does work. If anyone want's an example of how I did so I'd be happy to provide a code sample though!